# Execute Code Each Time a Fragment in FramentStatePagerAdapter is viewed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to create a `SlidingTabLayout` with 3 tabs. I want to do something each time a `Fragment` is viewed on my screen. I've tried putting what I want to happen inside the `onStart()` of the respective fragment like so:

```
public void onStart() {
    //Do This
}
```

but it only works when the `Fragment` is moved 2 fragments away (i.e. 1st to 3rd, 3rd to 1st). Is there a way to do something each time a fragment is viewed on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override `setUserVisibleHint()`

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) { 
       // here fragment is visible to user
    }
    else {  
    }

  }
}
```